# Angular 2. PrimeNG listbox not working

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a reactive form with two controls. One control is a dropdown that selects a country. The other control is a list of checkbox that selects the cities of the seleted country. I used primeNg's listbox in the last control (selection of cities). Now, I'm having a problem using primeng listbox. The problem is once I select a city all other cities is also selected. I'm also getting a null values in the second control of the form (selection of cities) even if there is a selected cities.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    countryForm : FormGroup;

    countries: Country [] ;

    constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { 
       this.countries = [
        {name:'USA', continent:'North America', cities :[
           {name: 'New York'} , { name: 'Los Angeles'} 
          ]},
        {name:'UK', continent:'Europe', cities :[
           {name: 'London'} , { name: 'Manchester'} , { name: 'Cambridge'} ,  { name: 'Bristol'}
          ]},
        {name:'Philippines', continent:'Asia', cities :[
           {name: 'Manila'} , { name: 'Davao'} , { name: 'Cebu'}
          ]},
         {name:'Japan', continent:'Asia', cities :[
           {name: 'Tokyo'} , { name: 'Kyoto'} , { name: 'Yokohama'}
          ]},
      ]
    }

    listOfCities: City [];

    ngOnInit() {
      this.countryForm= this.fb.group({
        selectedCountry:null,
        selectedCities: null
      });
      this.countryForm.controls['selectedCountry'].valueChanges.subscribe(
        value => {
          if(this.countryForm.controls['selectedCountry'].value!=null){
            this.listOfCities = this.countryForm.controls['selectedCountry'].value.cities;
          }
          else{
            this.listOfCities = [];
          }
      });
    }

    resetCountrySelection(){
      this.countryForm.controls['selectedCountry'].setValue(null);
      this.countryForm.controls['selectedCities'].setValue([]);

    }
}
```

Here's the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/yO4mNQveTyJgsvF9wUFE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

in component.ts

```
listOfCities: SelectItem [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.countryForm= this.fb.group({
    selectedCountry:null,
    selectedCities: null
  });
  this.countryForm.controls['selectedCountry'].valueChanges.subscribe(
    value => {
      if(this.countryForm.controls['selectedCountry'].value!=null){
        this.listOfCities = this.countryForm.controls['selectedCountry'].value.cities.map((v)=>{return {label:v.name, value:v.name} });
      }
      else{
        this.listOfCities = [];
      }
  });
}
```

convert listOfCities to array the SelectItem and apply function map to cities and put {label:, value:} and in template change:

```
 <p-listbox [options]="listOfCities" formControlName="selectedCities" [(ngModel)]="coutries1"  multiple="multiple" checkbox="checkbox" [style]="{'margin-top':'10px','min-height':'500px','width':'100%','max-height':'500px'}" >
        <template let-city pTemplate="body">
          <span style="font-size:12px;">{{city.label}}</span>
        </template>
      </p-listbox>
```

and create array of string:

```
coutries1: string[]; // selected city
```

in template put this

```
[(ngModel)]="coutries1"
```

Comment: hi can you apply that in my plnkr. Having a hard time implementing it.